# no repeating numbers in an array using c language

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, for-loop, unique

prompt the user to enter 10 integers and if there was a repeated number it will ask again 10 integers and
if there are no repeated numbers it will end the loops.

this is the expected output :

if I enter 10 numbers the program will review the array if there was a repeated number and if there is, it will ask to user  to input again 10 integer. the loops will end if there is no repeated numbers.

```
Enter 10 elements in the array :
Input 1: 1
Input 2: 2
Input 3: 3
Input 4: 4
Input 5: 5
Input 6: 5
Input 7: 5
Input 8: 6
Input 9: 7
Input 10: 8
5 is repeated, please enter numbers again // the 5 repeated in the array.

Enter 10 elements in the array :
Input 1: 1
Input 2: 2
Input 3: 3
Input 4: 4
Input 5: 5
Input 6: 6
Input 7: 7
Input 8: 8
Input 9: 9
Input 10: 0
There are no repeated numbers!
```

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() 
{ 
    int array[10]; 
    int i,j ,num=10;
    int n = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]); 

    int visited[n];
    
    do{
        printf("\n");
        printf("Enter %d elements in the array : \n", num);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            printf("Input %i: ",i+1);
            scanf("%d", &array[i]);
        }
    
        for(i=0; i < n; i++)
       
            if(visited[i] == 0){
                int count = 1;
        
                for(j = i+1; j < n; j++) { 
                    // if appears again in the array 
                    if(array[i] == array[j]) 
                    { // increase count & mark index visited 
                        count++; 
                        visited[j] = 1; 
                    } 
                } // 
            
                if(count >= 1){
                    printf("%d is repeated, please enter numbers again ",array[i]);
                    printf("\n");
                    break;
                }else{
                    printf("There are no repeated numbers!");
                    break;
                } 
            }
    }while(!array[i]); 
}
```

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: `int visited[n];` should be reset at each attempt (including the first one). Aside why do you have `n` *and* `num`?

Comment: What is this output? Is this what you get? Is it what you want? In what way differs your result from expected result?

Comment: OT: As user of your program I would be annoyed by repeating **all input** in case a single number was repeated. Why not check for repeated numbers on the fly...

Comment: The lack of proper indentation makes it real hard to read your code

Comment: I tried to fix the indentation for you but gave up. You are mixing two styles, i.e `{` at the end of the line versus `{` at a new line. Select the style you like and stick to it. Further, you some times omit `{` which is a pretty bad idea for multi line code blocks.

Comment: sorry it was a typo

Comment: The `if(count >= 1)`  code block contains a `break` statement in both the "true" and the "false" part. That must be a bug as it will break no matter what.

Comment: @Eugeo 1) Your question is not clear. Edit the question and add a description of the problem you have. 2) Fix indentation, i.e. use 4 spaces for each level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable length array `visited` was not initialized

```
int visited[n];
```

So for example this if statement

```
if(visited[i] == 0){
```

invokes undefined behavior.

This if statement

```
        if(count >= 1){
            printf("%d is repeated, please enter numbers again ",array[i]);
            printf("\n");
            break;
```

does not make a sense because even if a value is not repeated in the source array nevertheless initially `count` is set to 1

```
  if(visited[i] == 0){
        int count = 1;
```

There is no need to define an auxiliary array to resolve the problem.

And the condition in the do-while statement

```
}while(!array[i]);
```

also does not make sense.

The program can look for example the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{ 
    enum { N = 10 };
    int array[N];
    
    int repeated = N;

    do
    {
        printf("\n");
        printf( "Enter %d elements in the array :\n", N );

        for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
        {
            printf( "Input %i: ", i + 1 );
            scanf( "%d", &array[i] );
        }
    
        repeated = N;
        
        for ( int i = 0; i < repeated; i += repeated == N )
        {
            int j = i + 1;
            while ( j < N && array[j] != array[i] ) j++;
           
            if ( j != N ) repeated = i;
        }
            
        if ( repeated != N )
        {
            printf( "%d is repeated, please enter numbers again.\n", array[repeated] );
        }
        else
        {
            puts( "There are no repeated numbers!" );
        } 
    } while( repeated != N ); 
}
```

Comment: @Eugeo If your problem is resolved then close your question selection the best answer and your reputation will be increased.:)